# OpenLayers 4 moving polygon like a circle with Modify interaction

Tags: openlayers, modify-interaction

In example http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html when you hover on the center of the circle appears a point and you can move circle. Is it possible to do the same for the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your expectations from your description. As a circle has a center to draw it, it differs from getting a center in a polygon to drag it.

From my viewpoint, you should look at [this other official demo](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/translate-features.html) to translate/move features like polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check this example. --> [ol3 example draw shapes](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html)

You can draw squares, rectangles, or even stars